# Scroll bar should appear on zooming(scaling) svg image

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, zooming, scale

I am trying to zoom an svg image.I want the scroll bar to appear when the image is zoomed(especially when it grows beyond svg) so that the user can scroll to see different parts of the image.Here is my code.

```
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function slided(level){
        var svg=d3.select("g");
        svg.attr("transform","scale("+level+")");
    }
</script>
<div style="height:650;width:650;overflow:scroll;border:solid red">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" >
        <g>
        <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="100">
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" step="0.1" oninput="slided(this.value);">
```

**[Fiddle demonstrating this problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/rv68m406/1/)**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix:

## [Fiddle fixing the scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/rv68m406/)

So the problem is that you're blowing up the `<g>` tag and not the SVG itself, which is being contained by your SVG.  You're scaling up just a portion of the `svg`, which won't increase the dimensions of the image, and thus won't cause the scroll to fire.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, just use level and the circle radius (the number 200 in the function is the diameter - 2*radius ) to calculate the width and height of the svg element :)

Hope it will help you out :)

```js
 function slided(level) {
   var svg = d3.select('svg');
   var g = d3.select("g");
   g.attr("transform", "scale(" + level + ")");
   svg.attr("width", 200 * level);
   svg.attr("height", 200 * level);
 }
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <g>
      <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" step="0.1" oninput="slided(this.value);">
```

Comment: what if i don't have a circle inside the svg?..say I have a graph with multiple nodes and edges inside a g element..

Comment: That would be another question :)

Comment: Thank you very much..I took the container element's size instead